# I want to create a Terraform list of maps with some items in the list being conditional

Tags: terraform

How can I achieve the following:

I want to add map objects to a list based on whether they are passed as empty or not in the root module. So if this is passed in the variables

```
A = { foo = bar }
B = {}
C = { foo = bar }
```

then I would expect the `final_list` variable to be the one below

```
# main.tf
final_list = [{A}, {C}]
```

If there are alternate ways of achieving this (ie by using boolean flags), I'm ok with using those as well.

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for that?

Comment: @MaciejRostański Not sure, just asked to know if OP had tried something.

Comment: Ah, i thought irony was behind the corner. Still, I have bothered to provide the code for this wierd requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want filter usage like this:

```
locals {
  a = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
  b = {}
  c = {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  merge = [
    for map in [local.a,local.b,local.c] :
      map if map != {}
  ]
}

output "merge" {
  value = local.merge
}
```

Comment: Comparing to `{}` is risky because that will succeed only if the source value is an empty object, _not_ if it's an empty map. I would suggest `length(map) != 0` instead, because that will work for both object types and map types.

Comment: @MartinAtkins even better. Agreed.